# Side View Mirror Repair on 2014 Ford Edge

Tags: ford, mirrors

So i hit my side view mirror coming out of my garage the other day.  The housing is completely in tact and not damaged at all.  All the mechanics are working properly, i can still adjust the mirror and the lights still come on.  The mirror isnt cracked or damaged at all either.  My problem is there must have been a clip or something that holds the mirror part into the housing.  The mirror is very wobbly when driving and i'm afraid it is going to fall out.  How can i fix this problem?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Your description is a little lacking to me. I'm not quite sure, is the mirror still in the housing and moves very freely? Or has it actually came out of the housing? If still in the housing, I'd suggest there is something inside which is broken and not fixable.

Comment: The mirror is still in the housing and is extremely wobbly.  I believe when i hit it on the garage it bent back possibly snapping a clip off the backing plate.  The mirror isnt cracked at all but is just very loose in the housing.

Comment: I am in the same situation ,except I cracked the mirror. A couple plastic clips are broken off ; I am expecting to epoxy the new mirror in place .

Answer (score 0):

So, it's difficult to tell exactly what was damaged, but I suspect it was one of the plastic tab kanidingusskoobles (yes, that is the term, do not doubt) that may be pulled off the mirror glass backing, broken off, or *maybe* just popped out.

What I suggest is to move (joystick) the mirror inward so that it points at the vehicle.  This will create enough of an edge on the outside that you can get your fingers in, and *gently* pry the mirror glass away from the housing.

I will pop free.  It just snaps in anyway.  You will then be able to see if the kanidingusskooble is broken (requiring a new mirror glass - not that expensive) or merely popped free, which only requires realignment and some careful pressing back in until everything snaps into place.

If you're lucky, joystick the mirror back to a center position, and apply even pressure with multiple fingers across the mirror glass until you hear several clicks and pops.  If the mirror no longer wobbles, you're successful.

Comment: Google says:  “Your search - kanidingusskooble - did not match any documents.” Huh? You said “do not doubt” Am I doing this wrong? Perhaps not an English word?

Comment: @zipzit Well, there you go.  You doubted me and look what happened...  I don't know what that thing is called.  Do you?  The ovoid knobby bit(s) that locks into the motor carrier on a side view mirror.  It's a *German* word, but likely not from the Germany you know . . .

Comment: . . . And technically, it's an ß (grapheme Eszett) and should have been capitalized, since it's a "German" fake noun.  **Kandingußküble**  Roughly translated, "sacrificial plastic ovoid bit that either snaps into place or snaps off".